# Exception handling using ftplib package in Python

Tags: python, exception, ftp, ftplib

I'm new to `ftplib` and FTP in Python, I'm testing a simple script provided by the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.error_reply

```
try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.us.debian.org')
    ftp.login('111', '111')
except ftplib.all_errors as err:
    print(f'Error: ' + str(err))
```

This returns `Error: 503 Login with USER first.`, if I add `ftp.set_debuglevel(2)` this will tell me more detailed info:

```
*cmd* 'USER 111'
*put* 'USER 111\r\n'
*get* '331 This FTP server is anonymous only.\n'
*resp* '331 This FTP server is anonymous only.'
*cmd* 'PASS ***'
*put* 'PASS ***\r\n'
*get* '503 Login with USER first.\n'
*resp* '503 Login with USER first.'
Error: 503 Login with USER first.
```

It tells me additional info like `This FTP server is anonymous only`.

So I also tried:

```
try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.us.debian.org')
except ftplib.all_errors as err:
    print(f'Error: ' + str(err))
try:
    #ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
    ftp.login('111', '111')
except ftplib.all_errors as err:
    print(f'Error: ' + str(err))
```

This still won't tell me `This FTP server is anonymous only`
I wonder if I'm missing something, and can someone tell me what's the best practice to do exception handeling for FTP? Any examples? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not really related to `ftplib` but to the so called ftp anonymous mode.

FTP is a rather old protocol, and it requires the client to present credentials to the server. It was not suited for public servers, so the special `ftp` or `anonymous`(*) user was used for *anonymous* logging (this is optional for most FTP servers). Usage was to pass either `ftp` as the password, or the user mail address to let the server admin know who used their service.

So here you should use:

```
try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.us.debian.org')
    ftp.login('ftp', 'ftp')     # or ftp.login('anonymous', 'guest')
except ftplib.all_errors as err:
    print(f'Error: ' + str(err))
```

---

RFC 1635 only defines the user `anonymous` and recommend `guest` password, but most of the servers I have used also accepted `ftp`

Comment: So that's exactly the same with the first block of code I posted in the original question?

Comment: @Cecilia: except that my code use the *anonymous* `ftp` user name...

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: I had always used `ftp` but you are right, RFC 1635 speaks of `anonymous`. Post edited...